# How do I integrate CLIPS.net library into VB 2010?

Tags: vb.net, clips

I'm making an expert system using VB.net 2010
I already downloaded the Mommosoft.ExpertSystem.dll in CLIPS.NET
Assuming that I already made the Knowledge-based file with CLIPS, how to I integrate it to VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you right click on solution file > click Add References >  add the Mommosoft.ExpertSystem.dll

Then in your VB.Net project you will then be able to call methods in the DLL, eg

```
Mommosoft.ExpertSystem.DoSomething()
```